# maven create jar with dependencies (Eclipse plugin)

Tags: jar, maven-2, dependencies, export

I wanted to export a project from Eclipse with the Maven plugin with

```
clean package
```

The project has several dependencies, one from my workspace, and several fom e.g. Apache. The export took place, the .jar file was created. I added the main file entry to manifest.mf manually.
When i tried to run the jar, i got an error message:

```
no calssDeffoundError: com.apache.org.common.ApplicationCOntxt. ...   
Could not find main class hu.bz.test.Main.
```

How can i export a jar file with the dependencies using Maven?

Answer (score 1):

Create jar by using maven assembly plugin and its jar-with-dependencies configuration -> http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies